# Web api not working after project name and namespaces change

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity

I changed my project name and namespaces.  My project worked completely before this, but afterwards my token provider works and the token generated correctly and I can login, but my other apicontroller is not working.

I used routeprefix and route attribute above of functions

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

---

My project is a single page application with identity token based asp.net and web api 2 ( owin ) and I use angularjs for the frontend.

---

Errors:

message: "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:6611/api/Online/Alarms?unit=A'."

messageDetail: "No type was found that matches the controller named 'Online'."

Or

"Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Report'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('api/{controller}/{id}') found multiple controllers defined with the same name but differing namespaces, which is not supported."

Comment: do you have route attribute defined in your controller ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clean your bin folder and try again.

Comment: It would help if you explained *why* cleaning one's bin folder would help.